# How does google calculate metrics for mobile apps based on page views

Tags: android, google-analytics

I use google analytics for my mobile, and i use `trackPageView` method to register a page view on my application. When i see in google analytics page, average visit duration is around 16 mins or for some regions it's around 32 mins+. 
I want to understand how the metrics like "Average Visit Duration" , "Visitors", "count of visits" and "visits" are calculated based on the pageViews i am sending to google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Each pageview is registered with a timestamp. So GA calculates visit duration as (timestamp recorded on last page - timestamp recorded on first page). So if a visitor sequences is:

A -> B -> C -> D

Visit duration = timestamp(D) - timestamp(A)

Note, that GA cannot determine how much time was spent on page D itself since there is no reference to a subsequent pageview (and therefore timestamp) that it can use to make that calculation.

So in reality:

Visit duration = time spent on A + time spent on B + time spent on C

For definitions of the other terms, the best place to look would be Google Analytics' helpful glossary: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99118